# What is the exact Query To add two rows from different coloums?

Tags: mysql

I am totally new to this community, and I have a query below which is giving the wrong answer when I am adding two rows from different columns.

```
SELECT tw.name, fb.name, SUM(fb.follow + tw.follow) 
FROM fb, tw 
WHERE fb.name = 20 AND tw.name=20;
```

Actually the answer should be 4:

```
+------+------+--------------------------+
| name | name | SUM(fb.follow+tw.follow) |
+------+------+--------------------------+
| 20   | 20   |                        8 |
+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Table **fb**:

```
    +----+------+--------+
    | id | name | follow |
    +----+------+--------+
    |  1 | 20   |      1 |
    |  2 | 20   |      1 |
    +----+------+--------+
```

Table **tw**:

```
    +----+------+--------+
    | id | name | follow |
    +----+------+--------+
    |  1 | 20   |      1 |
    |  2 | 20   |      1 |
    +----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options such as:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(follow) FROM fb WHERE name = 20)
    + (SELECT SUM(follow) FROM tw WHERE name = 20);
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(follow) FROM (
    SELECT follow FROM fb WHERE name = 20
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT follow FROM tw WHERE name = 20
) as u;
```

The query in the question has one problem:

```
SELECT tw.name,fb.name,SUM(fb.follow+tw.follow) 
FROM fb, tw 
WHERE fb.name = 20 AND tw.name=20;
```

- values are counted twice because `fb CROSS JOIN tw` (i.e. `fb, tw`) duplicates each `follow` value

This is the result of the `CROSS JOIN` query without `SUM`after duplication:

```
id  name    follow  id  name    follow
1   20      1       1   20      3
2   20      2       1   20      3
1   20      1       2   20      4
2   20      2       2   20      4
```

Note that values (all `1`) have been replaced by `1, 2, 3, 4` because it is easier to see the problem.